# Use an Oracle database with forms authentication in an MVC3 application

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I've written a simple MVC3 application and followed a tutorial on how to set up authenticated users. The tutorial used a SQL server Express database.

**Is it possible to use an Oracle database instead of SQL server?**

Is it just a case of changing the connection string in the web.config to point at the Oracle database... or is it a bit more in-depth than that?

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" 
             connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated     Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much more in-depth than changing the connection string in the web.config.

1. you need a provider for Oracle
2. sqlServer supports Integrirty Authentication which is harder to accomplish with Oracle

Comment: should I be looking at the standard ODP or the entity framework beta 3? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Depends if your using the EntityFramework or not, if you do then you need the BETA version

Comment: I ended up writing a custom provider to work with either SQL or Oracle databases (the 2 we use at work).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [tutorial](http://quysnhat.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/using-membership-with-oracle-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) you may checkout. It uses the ODP.NET driver.