# How to configure ASP.net MVC 4 Application with oracle data provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g

I have Asp.net mvc 4 application
This is a connection string

```
<add name="OracleConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;User Id=RABS;Password=*******;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
```

Also installed on my machine oracle 11g R2 Express and Oracle data provider for .net
{ ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20)} from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

When i create model class and generate Controller i faced this error message 
unable to find the requested .net framework data provider

Answer (score 0):

You will keep getting errors because the solution is not as simple as changing the connection string. Look at the answers to this similar question: [Use an Oracle database with forms authentication in an MVC3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562734/use-an-oracle-database-with-forms-authentication-in-an-mvc3-application?rq=1)

One of the answers suggests taking a look at this tutorial: http://quysnhat.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/using-membership-with-oracle-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3/